# Error when reading values from excel files using Apache POI 4.1.1

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am attempting to read values from an excel file using Apache POI and I am encountering the following error message:

```
org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.setEntityExpansionLimit(I)Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions;
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:66) ~[poi-ooxml-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:657) ~[poi-ooxml-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:180) ~[poi-ooxml-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:282) ~[poi-ooxml-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:303) ~[poi-ooxml-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
    at cfo.metrics.loading.MetricsMonthlyHelper.getIndvEventValues(MetricsMonthlyHelper.java:117) [lib/:?]
    at cfo.metrics.loading.MetricsMonthlyHelper.getAllExcelValues(MetricsMonthlyHelper.java:2190) [lib/:?]
    at cfo.metrics.loading.MetricsDBLoaderMonthly.main(MetricsDBLoaderMonthly.java:23) [lib/:?]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:56) ~[poi-ooxml-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:63) ~[poi-ooxml-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.setEntityExpansionLimit(I)Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions;
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLTypeLoader.<clinit>(POIXMLTypeLoader.java:43) ~[poi-ooxml-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.ThemesTable.<init>(ThemesTable.java:86) ~[poi-ooxml-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:56) ~[poi-ooxml-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:63) ~[poi-ooxml-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
    ... 7 more
```

I am using the following jar files for my project poi-4.1.1.jar, poi-ooxml-4.1.1.jar and poi-ooxml-schemas-4.1.1.jar. 
Has anybody encountered the above error and can shed some light on what the root cause is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For poi-ooxml-4.1.1.jar, you should use xmlbeans-3.1.0.jar, see:

```
+- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:4.1.1:compile
|  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.11:compile
|  +- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.4:compile
|  \- org.apache.commons:commons-math3:jar:3.6.1:compile
+- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:4.1.1:compile
|  +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:jar:4.1.1:compile
|  |  \- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:3.1.0:compile
|  +- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.19:compile
|  \- com.github.virtuald:curvesapi:jar:1.06:compile
```

Comment: Great thanks! Had an older version of xmlbeans on the classpath, removed it and only had xmlbeans-3.1.0.jar which resolved the issue.