# How can I upgrade org.apache.poi of poi-ooxml from 4.1.1 to 5.0.0?

Tags: java, maven, build, apache-poi, xmlbeans

I am trying to update:

```
groupId  org.apache.poi
artifactId  poi-ooxmlartifactId
version  4.1.1  version
```

to:

```
version 5.0.0  version
```

But for code it fail for 5.0.0 as:

> java: cannot access org.apache.xmlbeans.xml.stream.XMLInputStream
> class file for org.apache.xmlbeans.xml.stream.XMLInputStream not found

Comment: Do you have an older version of XMLBeans on your classpath? Looks like it is using an old one, not the one that Apache POI pulls in

Comment: this looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62177218/error-when-reading-values-from-excel-files-using-apache-poi-4-1-1